# get configuration file depending on enviorment in a react app

Tags: reactjs, npm

I've used create react app to create a react application. Actually I want to deploy my application on a dev server (and a production server in the future).

I m new in npm and react and I dont know how may I set the import of my configuration file depending on the enviorment where the app is (in localhost, dev and prod). I want to avoid solution like :

```
const configFile = islocalhost ? './localhost.config' : './dev.env';
```

Is there a better solution ?

I tryed to set NODE_ENV too but in my js files I dont have access to process.env ...

I am using windows and the servers are Linux based.

Comment: Do you have environment variables that tell you where you are?  If not, your question is pretty vague and what you have written is perfectly valid.

Comment: How may I set environment variable that tells me where I am ?

Comment: Kind of a chicken & egg question there.  Do your servers follow some kind of naming convention or subnetted in a different way than production?

Comment: I havent understand your question

Comment: I ve tried to use something like : "dev": "NODE_ENV=localhost ..." but in my JS I havent access to process.env.NODE_ENV

Comment: if you have used create-react-app, you should have access to process.env.NODE_ENV, and always have access in node/express. Can you link a repo so we can have a look?

Comment: I dont have access to the process.env unfortunatlly, I not using webpack